# Open GL with c# windows form

Tags: c#, opengl

I am using open gl with c# windows form , now I put a timer in the form but during the run time ,the timer tick void was not called 
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Please share your code, impossible to answer without it.

Answer (score -1):

No example given.

Most obvious check would be, have you started the timer yet?

What sort of timer are you using?

Have you set the tick listener? (you will need to do this even if you drag the timer into the visual side of Visual Studio)

Try this tutorial: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

Bellow is taken from the tutorial...

```
static void Start()
{
_l = new List<DateTime>(); // Allocate the list
_timer = new Timer(3000); // Set up the timer for 3 seconds
//
// Type "_timer.Elapsed += " and press tab twice.
//
_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
_timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it
}
static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
_l.Add(DateTime.Now); // Add date on each timer event
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions speculatively. If you have to guess at what the answer *might* be, then the question isn't clear. So it should not be answered until it gets cleared up.

Comment: I couldn't comment, and I had a potential answer. I would rather provide my thoughts if ti would help anyone seeing as they are not replying and probably wont reply... Seeing as someone might come into the same issue I thought answering it might be worth a try seeing as that could indeed be one of the issues.